# how do I use Pivot in Sql Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have a table that stores the data as follows:
username   status 
user1              HT 
user2               EC 
user1               PR 
user1               EC 
user2               HT

I need result something like this

username  HT  EC PR GrandTotal  
user1           1      1     1      3  
user2           1      1     0      2  
Total           2      2     1      5

please anybody help me.   Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It is simple when Status values are fixed.

```
select 
    username,
    sum(case when status='HT' then 1 else 0 end) as HT,
    sum(case when status='EC' then 1 else 0 end) as EC,
    sum(case when status='PR' then 1 else 0 end) as PR,
    count(*) as total
from
    table
group by
    username
WITH ROLLUP
```

If they are dynamic, you need to use http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/10840/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server-2005.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
        USE AdventureWorks
    GO
    -- Creating Test Table
    CREATE TABLE Product(Cust VARCHAR(25), Product VARCHAR(20), QTY INT)
    GO
    -- Inserting Data into Table
    INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
    VALUES('KATE','VEG',2)
    INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
    VALUES('KATE','SODA',6)
    INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
    VALUES('KATE','MILK',1)
    INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
    VALUES('KATE','BEER',12)
    INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
    VALUES('FRED','MILK',3)
    INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
    VALUES('FRED','BEER',24)
    INSERT INTO Product(Cust, Product, QTY)
    VALUES('KATE','VEG',3)
    GO
    -- Selecting and checking entires in table
    SELECT *
    FROM Product
    GO
    -- Pivot Table ordered by PRODUCT
    SELECT PRODUCT, FRED, KATE
    FROM (
    SELECT CUST, PRODUCT, QTY
    FROM Product) up
    PIVOT (SUM(QTY) FOR CUST IN (FRED, KATE)) AS pvt
    ORDER BY PRODUCT
    GO
    -- Pivot Table ordered by CUST
    SELECT CUST, VEG, SODA, MILK, BEER, CHIPS
    FROM (
    SELECT CUST, PRODUCT, QTY
    FROM Product) up
    PIVOT (SUM(QTY) FOR PRODUCT IN (VEG, SODA, MILK, BEER, CHIPS)) AS pvt
    ORDER BY CUST
    GO
    -- Unpivot Table ordered by CUST
    SELECT CUST, PRODUCT, QTY
    FROM
    (
    SELECT CUST, VEG, SODA, MILK, BEER, CHIPS
    FROM (
    SELECT CUST, PRODUCT, QTY
    FROM Product) up
    PIVOT
    ( SUM(QTY) FOR PRODUCT IN (VEG, SODA, MILK, BEER, CHIPS)) AS pvt) p
    UNPIVOT
    (QTY FOR PRODUCT IN (VEG, SODA, MILK, BEER, CHIPS)
    ) AS Unpvt
    GO
    -- Clean up database
    DROP TABLE Product
    GO

    ResultSet:
    -- Selecting and checking entires in table
    Cust Product QTY
    ------------------------- -------------------- -----------
    KATE VEG 2
    KATE SODA 6
    KATE MILK 1
    KATE BEER 12
    FRED MILK 3
    FRED BEER 24
    KATE VEG 3

    -- Pivot Table ordered by PRODUCT
    PRODUCT FRED KATE
    -------------------- ----------- -----------
    BEER 24 12
    MILK 3 1
    SODA NULL 6
    VEG NULL 5

    -- Pivot Table ordered by CUST
    CUST VEG SODA MILK BEER CHIPS
    ------------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
    FRED NULL NULL 3 24 NULL
    KATE 5 6 1 12 NULL

    -- Unpivot Table ordered by CUST
    CUST PRODUCT QTY
    ------------------------- -------- -----------
    FRED MILK 3
    FRED BEER 24
    KATE VEG 5
    KATE SODA 6
    KATE MILK 1
    KATE BEER 12 12
```

Reference:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/

Comment: @SunilKumar you'r welcome. Remember to vote up and mark it as your answer if it is helpful to you.